# MD5 Hash Issue with Java

Tags: java, md5

A java implementation creates two different digest for a same input string, if i run as stand alone application or running inside a web application.

The standalone application matches with oracle dbms
The implementation is

```
    MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

    if (md5 != null) {
        md5.reset();
        newHashByte = md5.digest(msg.getBytes());
    }

    newHash = convertToString(newHashByte);
```

Hex to String conversion implementation is

```
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(64);

for (int i = 0; i < digestBits.length; i++)
    hexDigit(result, digestBits[i]);

return result.toString();
```

Highly appreciate if you could help us resolving this.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect you have different default encodings. Use the correct encoding like this,

```
newHashByte = md5.digest(msg.getBytes("utf-8"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Where does `msg` come from in each case?  I think it's likely you have a newline character on the end in one case but not the other.  It's also possible that your character encodings are set differently somehow in the two scenarios.  I highly doubt that anything else in your example is changing except `msg`.